# Relationship between ForeignKeys within a model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django so pardon if this is a simple question but I've had a hard time phrasing it. I've looked for an answer quite a while already.

Suppose I'm building a very simple gradebook app.

models.py (with code ommited)

```
class Course(models.Model):
    ...

class Student(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
    ...

class Assignment(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    ...
```

Is there a way to set the models.py up so that if I add an Assignment to a Course, it automatically associates the Assignment to all the students enrolled in the course?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to achieve this result. You could use the [signals framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) for connecting the post_save action of one new assignment to trigger duplicating that assignment out to every student in the course

Or you could [reimplement the save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) of the model to do the same thing directly when save is called

Or you could create a utility type classmethod on the model like create_assignment_for_course.  Because this would show up also on the Course instances, the general approach is to put this on [a custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance). The manager is what lives at the Model.object   attribute. 
Of course you would have to specifically use this classmethod/manager method when creating an assignment for the whole course